# Retrofit best way multiple requests or one big request?

Tags: android, performance, android-studio, httprequest, retrofit

**My problem:**

I have a profile of my users with dozens of information(basic like name, about.... location, rating... and so on)

in my case its ok, but if the internet is bad, it takes time to get the information.

**My question:**

***Which is better?(performance, server performance, internet consumption)***

*One big request, like i doing*

or

*multiple requests, 1: name, about... 2: ratings... 3: locations and so on*

**?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't make multiple requests. One big request is fine.

The best way is, Get all the information once and store it to local.

Make another API which only checks, whether the profile update or not. If the profile updated, get all info from the server and update with local data.

It will reduce the data consumption.